# AutoComplete more than a column in janus multicolumn combobox

Tags: c#, vb.net, combobox, janus

I have a Janus multicolumn combobox in my windows form project. I use this code to fill it:

```
  mcbCustomerId.ValueMember = "ID"
  mcbCustomerId.DisplayMember = "FarsiFamily"
  mcbCustomerId.DataMember = "TblCustomer"
  mcbCustomerId.DataSource = ds
```

I have four columns in this combobox, but only FarsiFamily combobox is in autocomplete mode. I want to set autocomplete mode for other columns. How can I do that?

Comment: You can set autocomplete mode in form's UI design.

Comment: autocomplete is true but only work on displaymember

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the OnTextBoxTextChanged method to cycle through columns and filter the list.

Here is an example on how to do it:

```
public partial class MultiColumnSearchCombo : MultiColumnCombo
{
       protected override void OnTextBoxTextChanged(EventArgs e)
       {
          GridEXFilterCondition internalFilter = new GridEXFilterCondition();

          String str = TextBox.Text;

          foreach (GridEXColumn column in DropDownList.Columns)
          {
               if (!column.Visible)
                   continue;

               GridEXFilterCondition filterCondition = new GridEXFilterCondition(column, ConditionOperator.Contains, str);

               internalFilter.AddCondition(LogicalOperator.Or, filterCondition);
          }

          DropDownList.ApplyFilter(internalFilter);

       }

}
```

Comment: how can i override it?

Comment: By creating a new class that is inherited from MultiColumnCombo class.

Comment: i try itT but class can't inherit from janus controls

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example about how to inherit from Janus class.